# Combinatorics question about word length

Tags: combinatorics

Given a word $w$ we say that $w$ has periodicity $l$ if $w = v^k$ for some word $v$ of length $l$.

Problem: If $w$ is $m$ periodic and also $n$ periodic, then it is $gcd(m, n)$ periodic.

This seems easy, but I have had a mental block for the past hour.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $w=w_1w_2w_3w_4 \ldots w_t$. It is convenient to extend $w$ into an infinite
word by $t$-periodicity : put $w_{t+1}=w_1,w_{t+2}=w_2$ etc, and on the other side
$w_0=w_t, w_{-1}=w_{t-1}$ etc.

Then $w$ is $m$-periodic iff  $w_{i+m}=w_{i}$ for every integer $i$.

Suppose $w$ is both $n$-periodic and $m$-periodic ; let $g={\sf gcd}(n,m)$. By Bezout’s theorem, there are integers $a,b$ with $g=an+bm$. Then for any integer $i$,

$$
w_{i+g}=w_{i+an+bm}=w_{i+an}=w_i
$$

So $w$ is $g$-periodic as wished.